# Scrapy. Need to stop crawling pages and delete exists requests to those pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have spider which is scrapping site with news for a specific company. Spider should scrape all news first time and all next only fresh news. Here short flow

- I get a name of a company from DB and build a specific URL for them.
- Make request for all URLs
- Select news and make `yield`
- In pipeline made checks on the duplicate news.

I need stop scrap all URL which has relation to a company if count duplicates for this company are more 20(need stop make a request and parse). But for other companies spider should scrap news

Is it possible?

I can run spider for each company and stop spider after condition but I will have a lot of logs
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What works? What does not work as you expect?

Comment: I tried close spider when started to get duplicate news, check the news in a buffer and don't parse duplicate. But it is not what I need. I need to delete all request when counting duplicate > for example 10

Comment: Btw, I probably found another solution for it